# How can one automate promotion of an artifact to a feed view in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

Our build artifact is an Octopus nuget package. When the build is released it lands into the QA stage where the artifact is deployed through Octopus. This octopus consumes it directly from the Azure Artifacts nuget feed.

If the deployment and the subsequent tests are successful we want to promote the artifact to the Release view of the Azure Artifacts nuget feed, because we think it gives us a different nuget URL that can be used by another Octopus serving the next stage (for historic reasons we have dedicated Octopus per stage - working to change that, but it takes time).

We can promote manually, but we want to do it automatically. How can this be done?

We are testing it on on-premises TFS 2019 RC2.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

The suggested plugin does not seem to install on on-premises TFS 2019 RC2:

[image]

Comment: i suppose you would use rest api call from octopus

Comment: The promotion is the Azure DevOps operation. Let me attach a snapshot.

Comment: i know, thats what I meant, call ADO api from octopus when release succeeds

Comment: What is the REST API for feed promotion, I could not find it?

Comment: right, i dont see anything either. weird. probably feed has got its own api. questionmark

Answer (score 3):

Using PowerShell...

```
$organisationName = '' # Name of organisation
$projectName = '' # Name of project
$feedName = '' # Name of Azure Artifacts feed
$viewName = 'Release' # I believe this can also be Prerelease, but I've not tried it

# List of names of packages within Azure Artifacts feed to be promoted
$packagesToPromote = @('')

# Need a personal access token for this script to work
# PAT token should be assigned to Packaging (Read, Write and Manage) scopes
$azureArtifactsPAT = '' 
$AzureArtifactsPAT_Base64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($azureArtifactsPAT)"))
$restAPICallHeader = @{ Authorization = "Basic $AzureArtifactsPAT_Base64" }

$feedBaseURL = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$organisationName/$projectName/_apis/packaging/feeds"
$packageBaseURL = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/$organisationName/$projectName/_apis/packaging/feeds"

$feedIdURL = "$feedBaseURL/$feedName/?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$feedIdResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $feedIdUrl -Headers $restAPICallHeader -ContentType 'application/json')
$feedId = $feedIdResponse.id

$viewIdURL = "$feedBaseURL/$feedId/views/$viewName/?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$viewIdResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $viewIdUrl -Headers $restAPICallHeader -ContentType 'application/json')
$viewId = $viewIdResponse.id


$restAPICallBodyJson = @{
    views = @{
        op = 'add'
        path = '/views/-'
        value = "$viewId"
    }
}
$restAPICallBody = (ConvertTo-Json $restAPICallBodyJson)

foreach ($packageName in $packagesToPromote) {

    $packageQueryUrl = "$feedBaseURL/$feedId/packages?api-version=5.1-preview.1&packageNameQuery=$packageName"
    $packagesResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $packageQueryUrl -Headers $restAPICallHeader -ContentType 'application/json')
    $latestPackageVersion = ($packagesResponse.value.versions | ? { $_.isLatest -eq $True } | Select -ExpandProperty version)
    $encodedPackageVersion = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($latestPackageVersion)

    Write-Host "Package Name: $packageName"
    Write-Host "Package Version: $latestPackageVersion"

    $releaseViewURL = $packageBaseURL `
    + "/$($feedId)" `
    + "/nuget/packages/$packageName" `
    + "/versions/$encodedPackageVersion" `
    + "?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $releaseViewURL -Headers $restAPICallHeader -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $restAPICallBody
    Write-Host $response
}
```

For reference, the script above uses the following API calls:

**Feed Management - Get Feed**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/get%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

**Feed Management - Get Feed View**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/get%20feed%20view?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

**Artifact Details - Get Packages**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

**NuGet - Update Package Version**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: I'd just like to add - Yes, 'Prerelease' works as well.

Comment: This script has one flaw: it depends on the package name returning a single package. If you have packages named ToolsAz, ToolsRm, and Tools you cannot get the 'Tools' package in one call, so you must filter the result in the script.

Comment: In fact, the filter for 'latest version' is superfluous since the call returns only latest by default.

Comment: Thanks for this script. A word of caution, if your feed was created outside a project, you'll need to remove the reference to your project in the URLs. When creating a feed, you have the Scope option: Project or Organisation. The error is something like: "The feed with ID 'MyFeed' doesn't exist. The clue is in the documentation "The project parameter must be supplied if the feed was created in a project."

Answer (score 1):

As per [Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/views?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav#use-release-views-with-continuous-integrationdelivery) the marketplace task [Promote package to Release View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.vsts-promotepackage-task) is the recommended way to accomplish this from a CI/CD pipeline.

The repository can be found on [Github](https://github.com/renevanosnabrugge/vsts-promotepackage-task).

[image]

---

### Edit:

Since you are on-prem with a version that this task doesn't support. I would say that the comments about using the REST api would be the route you need to go in something like a powershell script.

Having never used the REST Api for this task I'm not exactly sure how the body is supposed to look for the request. However, it seems to be documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body).

My understanding of the [JSON Patch object](http://jsonpatch.com/) is limited, but I would think you might use the `replace` operation.

`{ "op": "replace", "path": "/view", "value": "@Release" }`

[This article](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/understanding-json-patch/) may also be helpful, but I still don't see anything that would relate to the `from` identifier on the `JsonPatchObject` definition in the REST Api documentation.

Comment: Have you installed it on an on-premises TFS 2019 RC2? Because it does not work for us.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Just FYI, I think it's expected that the @ symbol in @Release is omitted in the replace operation.

Comment: Hi I do not find where the above aforementioned package is recommended. It is still the case today?

Answer (score 1):

I also recently struggled with trying to implement version using TFS. I've produced some PowerShell scripts (adapting other scripts out on the web) to do package versioning.

https://gist.github.com/oceanexplorer/6a91930419b35c1923974af265777a5f

https://gist.github.com/oceanexplorer/35e0f26962018dc8578c745060365c15

The first step is my build pipeline I use the "Update AssemblyInfo" task to set the build version which then gets embedded into the DLL's.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo

Initially I embedded the above scripts with my project to get things going but eventually in my release pipeline I then have a task that deploys these build scripts via a "NuGet Install" task which effectively pulls them from a feed and unzips them.

In the release pipeline I then have a task "Version Package" which is a custom PowerShell script that calls functions defined in the two gists above, what these do is to unzip the NuGet packages that have been created from the build pipeline and placed in the artifact directory, applies the correct versioning to the package and zips it back up. I have used the following build number format in my build pipeline:

```
$(version.major).$(version.minor).$(version.patch).$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r)-CI

1.0.0.201902051-CI

This will produce a semantic build number format of:

1.0.0-alpha.201902051
```

I call the scripts using an inline PowerShell task

```
##-------------------------------------------
## Import Build Scripts
##-------------------------------------------
gci -Recurse "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\scripts\*.psm1" | ForEach-Object { Import-Module $_.FullName }

##-------------------------------------------
## Version Files
##-------------------------------------------
Expand-NugetPackages -packagesDirectory "$(artifact.directory)" -Verbose
Add-VersionToAssemblies -suffix "$(Release.EnvironmentName)" -semVer "2.0" -artifactsToApplyTo "nuspec" -isRelease $(isRelease) -Verbose
Compress-NugetPackages -packagesDirectory "$(artifact.directory)" -Verbose
```

Then a NuGet push task to push the package

[image: Nuget Push task]
Them another inline PowerShell script which sets the release view for the package feed:

```
##-------------------------------------------
## Import Build Scripts
##-------------------------------------------
gci -Recurse "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\scripts\*.psm1" | ForEach-Object { Import-Module $_.FullName }

##-------------------------------------------
## Set Package Quality
##-------------------------------------------
Set-PackageQuality -feedName "Libraries" -packageId $(nuget.packageId) -packageVersion $env:semanticVersion -packageQuality $(Release.EnvironmentName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something changed recently in the ADO RestApi.
What worked for me was sending a PATCH request like:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORGANIZATION/YOUR_PROJECT/_apis/packaging/feeds/YOUR_FEEDNAME/upack/packages/YOUR_PACKAGENAME/versions/YOUR_PACKAGEVERSION?api-version=5.1-preview.1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "views": {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/views/-",
    "value": "Release"
  }
}'
```